# Meteor selectors not working with Unexpected string error

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm following [this guid](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/managing-todos/)e and one of the selectors isn't working for me.
Here is some of my code:

```
Template.todoItem.events({
'click .delete-todo': function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var documentId = this._id;
  var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this task?");
  if(confirm){
    Todos.remove({ _id: documentId });
  }
}
'keyup [name=todoItem]': function(event){
  console.log("You just tapped a key on your keyboard.");
 }
});
```

And HTML of:

```
<template name="todoItem">
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="text" value="{{name}}" name="todoItem">
  [<a href="#" class="delete-todo">Delete</a>]
 </li>
</template>
```

When I try and run this code Meteor gives me the error: Errors prevented startup: While building the application: todos.js:32:5: Unexpected string

I think this is because of the `'keyup [name=todoItem]'` bit in the JavaScript. If anyone knows what's going on help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks, Alaister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error, the two event listeners need a comma between them.

On my mobile device, unable to format code.